# Windows 8 Slide out menu

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

What control do I need to create my own slide out menu (i.e. Charm menu) for my app?

I want to do this in `XAML`.

Comment: I don't know what to look for I saw an example at a  presentation but I'm not sure what control they used?

Comment: I've been looking at the Windows 8 code samples for the last hour or so...  I have not been able to find an example.  If you have a suggestion of a control or a place to look.  Please let me know.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the library from this blog post to create charm flyout controls: http://w8isms.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/charmflyout-another-charming.html

Comment: This blog post was exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Callisto by Tim Heuer https://github.com/timheuer/callisto I used the same in my @Win8RSSReader app

Comment: Thanks that looks like it might be even easier.  I appreciate the help.